# Compile attempt gives error that says "error: class, interface, or enum expected", but error points to Chinese character?

Tags: java, enums

I have been attempting to do a HelloWorld for an online Java class I started, but I have run into a weird error. I did look around on this website, and while I did see some similar instances of this error, none of them had the exact same issue that I'm having.

So for my class, I entered the code below (as instructed in the video, copied every letter, bracket, and symbol) into Notepad and saved it, set up javac, and attempted to run a javac.

```
public class HelloWorld {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println("Hello world!");

   }
}
```

Now when I run the javac, it gives me this error.

[image]

(The \ shows up like a weird W-like symbol on the command prompt for me, but it still functions properly).

The little arrow should point to the error in the text file, but the problem is it shows up as a Chinese character for some reason. I haven't been able to figure out what causes this, but my guess is it's something beyond the scope of this text document. However, my system doesn't use Chinese, and the system locale isn't in Chinese either, so I have no idea what it could be. I don't think it can be any of the brackets, as they look accurate to me, unless there's something I completely missed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try deleting the p and the whitespace before it, it seems you have a hidden caracter somewhere

Comment: The p was actually the very first character in my text document. I tried deleting the p just now, but it gives me the exact same error, except this time it says: 癤퓎blic class HelloWorld {

Comment: This and the weird W character would suggest to me that there is something very wrong with your PC. Good luck!

Comment: I realized the problem with the W character; my system locale was set to Korean instead of English (long story there). But now it's giving me a new error, which I will type up in a moment.

Comment: Sorry, but SO doens't work this way. It is not a place where you basically use us to fix your compiler errors. Thus: when this question is solved because of a simple "typo" copy/paste error - then consider deleting the question. Instead of completely rewriting it to fit your next problem.

Comment: But this problem wasn't a simple typo or copy paste error, it had to do with the way my system locale was set up. And I managed to figure it out anyway, as I wrote below.

Comment: And I was planning to make a new thread anyway if I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your program file has something in it that is being interpreted as a multi-byte character.  The character in error seems to be right before the "p" in `public` which is why the compiler is giving the error message.  It is expecting a keyword and getting a Chinese character.

What editor did you use?  I think the real problem is something about how your editor is set up.  This error message is just a symptom.  Another possibility is that your system is set up for interpreting certain byte sequences as Chinese.  That would explain "\ " being interpreted as a character and something starting with a curly brace and going through "p" being seen as a sequence of them.

Comment: I used Notepad with Windows 10 to do this. As I watched the aforementioned video, I typed it into the Notepad myself, without relying on any external editor to type it, and saved it as a .java file.

If possible, should I upload my text file here to see if there's anything that could be inspected?

Comment: I wonder if it's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding).  I don't know if any of those byte sequences could be interpreted as Chinese characters.

Comment: So I was able to figure out the problem, actually. This was interesting.
My system locale was set to Korean instead of English (long story there, not gonna go into that), and I was able to figure out that the W character was a result of the Korean system locale. This led me to a new error, where it said "illegal character: '\u00bb'" and "illegal character: '\u00bf'". 
I looked a bit into this, and it turns out that UTF-8 files (which it was saved as) would insert invisible characters at the start of the file. I saved it as an ANSI file instead, and it was able to convert it to a class file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows notepad is the worst txt editor,it will change your line breaks,and it will insert **UTF-8 BOM** into the text file that you edit.
2. For your instance,that's why your java file can't compile.
3. There's no one fixed ANSI encoding - there are lots of them. Usually when people say "ANSI" they mean "the default locale/codepage for my system" which is obtained via Encoding.Default, and is often Windows-1252 but can be other locales.